# Simple Gallon Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm attempting to build a simple web form that takes 3 number inputs and outputs one number based on this formula: (a*b*c)/271).

This is the code I have but nothing is displayed in the output.

Clearly I have almost no clue what I'm doing.

I appreciate all help:

```
<body>
<img id="logo"src="images/a&l.png" alt="A&L Cesspool"/>
<h1>Grease Trap Gallon Calculator<h2>
<form name=calculator">
<input label="length" type="number" id="a"> 
<input label="width" type="number" id="b">
<input label="height" type="number" id="c">
<input type=Button value=Calculate onClick="gallons();">
<input name="OUTPUT" id="output" SIZE="4" maxlength="6" >
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function gallons() {
var LENGTH = document.calculator.a.value;
var WIDTH = document.calculator.b.value;
var HEIGHT = document.calculator.c.value;
var Total =(LENGTH*WIDTH*HEIGHT)/271;
document.calculator.OUTPUT.value = Total;
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: You're also missing the opening quote on `<form name=calculator">` - should be `<form name="calculator">`.

Answer (score 3):

`document.forms.calculator`. There's no such thing as `document.calculator`. Also, form elements need `name` attributes to refer to them in form context, not IDs.

#### In other news

- You have unclosed quotes
- You have irregular naming conventions (`OUTPUT`, `a`, `Total`)
- You have irregular quotes policy (sometimes you have, sometimes you don't).

So basically

```
<form name="calculator">
    <input label="length" type="number" name="a">
    <input label="width" type="number" name="b">
    <input label="height" type="number" name="c">
    <input type=Button value=Calculate onClick="gallons();">
    <input name="OUTPUT" id="output" SIZE="4" maxlength="6">
</form>

function gallons() {
    var LENGTH = document.forms.calculator.a.value;
    var WIDTH = document.forms.calculator.b.value;
    var HEIGHT = document.forms.calculator.c.value;
    var Total = (LENGTH * WIDTH * HEIGHT) / 271;
    document.forms.calculator.OUTPUT.value = Total;
}
```

Please grab a proper tutorial from MDN or some similar good source, and start reading.

Comment: To be fair, you can reference inputs by `id`, but use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: @Dai: "In form context"

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `document.calculator` is not finding the element because its looking by id
change your form definition and it will work

```
<form name="calculator" id="calculator">
```